# Websphere variables not working same in WAS 8.5 and 8

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi, websphere-8

I currently work in WAS 8.5 and I create a Websphere variable called BACKBASE_CONFIG. I map this using the Bind file like this...

```
<env-entry name="backbase/config" value="${BACKBASE_CONFIG}\backbase.properties"/>
```

This works fine for me, however, when a coworker tries to deploy the same application on WAS 8.0 it doesn't fill in the env-entry in the app. Does anyone know how I can get this working in both? Web.xml would be fine as long as I can still use server or env variables to abstract the actual location.